# Use pip python-django instead apt

Tags: python, django

I have installed python-django in a ubuntu 14.04, unfortunately I need to use exactly that distribution, but it is unsupported now, to update django I used the pip, how do I use the newer version instead of the apt version?

Comment: Uninstall the apt version

Comment: Use a virtualenv.

Comment: I agree with e4c5 and JesseBakker. first create and virtual env and install django on it via pip

Answer (score 3):

You need virtualenv. It enables you to create a virtual python environment with its own packages (instead of system-wide packages).

First, install `python-virtualenv` package with `apt-get`:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv # or python3-virtualenv if you use python 3
```

And create a virtualenv:

```bash
$ virtualenv /home/user/venv
```

Then activate the virtualenv you created (after doing this, you will be using only the packages you installed in this virtualenv, ignoring the system-wide packages):

```bash
$ source /home/user/venv/bin/activate
```

Now you can install the packages you want:

```bash
$ pip install django==1.7 # replace 1.7 with the version you need
```

or if you want to install the latest version currently available (be careful here, in future you can install latest version and the version can be different from the version you worked on)

```bash
$ pip install django
```

After this point, whenever you run `python manage.py runserver` in a django project, you will be using the django package you installed in this virtualenv.

**Extra notes:**

You can save the packages you installed, in order to be able to install them again on another virtualenv:

```bash
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And then you can install the list of packages you saved later with:

```bash
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: There is no need to specify the version, considering that he's trying to use the latest version of it

Comment: @Av4t4r that is really a bad practice. If the virtual environment somehow gets deleted or he tries to install the same application on another virtualenv he will have to make sure the latest package version matches the version he worked on. The version ze wants to install is currently the latest version, that won't last forever.

Comment: He wanted the last version. Right after installing that one, he could pip freeze the environment and keep on installing the same version